# Return index of a list if condition is true using any() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = [['df','37s',''],['4d','34','jd']]
for lst in a:
    if any(i=='' for i in lst):
        print(lst.index(i)) # NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

The code above is indicative of what I want to do.

Is it possible to get the index of the `i` of `lst` that returned true in the `any()` method, without using an explicit for loop over `lst`, and if so how?

Comment: No point in trying to avoid explicitly iterating over your list, because **`any`** [explicitly iterates over your list anyways](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're merely confusing the scope of your subscript variable.  Try a more direct approach with the `index` method:

```
a = [['df','37s',''],['4d','34','jd']]
target = ''
for lst in a:
    if target in lst:
       print(lst.index(target))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've altered your problem description (note that sample output really helps), try this list comprehension:

```
print([pos for pos, lst in enumerate(a) if target in lst])
```

Output:

```
[0]
```

which indicates that a[0] is the only element that contains an empty string.

If I extend the input test to

```
a = [['df','37s',''],
     ['4d','34','jd'],
     ['one','','more', 'try']]
```

The output is

```
[0, 2]
```

Comment: he wants the index of target in `lst`, not the index in `a`.

Comment: His comment asked for the `index i of lst`, which isn't entirely clear.  That's why I separated my solutions into separate answers.  I'm hoping OP will clarify by choosing one of the posted solutions; I'll delete the one that doesn't match the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh ... someone voted this as useful.  Okay, I'll leave this answer alive for illustration, but please note that it does *not* solve the poster's intended problem statement.

Comment: I didn't realize the same person wrote both answers.

Answer (score 1):

To answer strictly the initial question: is it possible to get the indice that returned true in the any(), without making an explicit for.
Well, it is possible. But that does not mean that you should do it. Please do not use this code in production, it relies on Cpython implementation details. Use Prune's answer instead.

```
a = [['df','37s',''],['4d','34','jd']]

for lst in a:
    gen = (value == '' for i, value in enumerate(lst))

    if any(gen):
        i = gen.gi_frame.f_locals['i']
        print('i=',i)
        #i= 2
```